# Project failed to build with copy if newer option on linked file

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core console app referencing a .NET 4.5.1 project.
This 4.5.1 project has a file added as a link.

Everything is building correctly.

When I change my linked file from `Do not copy` to `Copy if newer`, my .NET Core project does not build anymore:

```
Failed to make the following project runnable: ConsoleApp1 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6) 
reason: Could not find file 'c:\users\nbedard\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\blop.config'.
```

In fact, the file is located in another location:

```
C:\Users\nbedard\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\blop.config
```

Looks like the .NET Core project does not reach the **Debug** folder.

Any idea what is going on?

[image]